# How to display python dict in html table

Tags: python-2.7

I have some data stored in a python dict and need to display it in a particular order in html. For example;

```
values = {
    server1 : {'key1' : 'b', 'key2' : 'd'},
    server2 : {'key1' : 'e', 'key2' : 'f'},
    server3 : {'key1' : 'g', 'key2' : 'h'},
    server4 : {'key1' : 'i', 'key2' : 'j'},
    server5 : {'key1' : 'k', 'key2' : 'l'},
    server6 : {'key1' : 'm', 'key2' : 'n'},
}
```

should be displayed as:

[image: img]

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly did you get stuck when trying to implement this? Can you show what you tried?

Comment: I'd recommend using `pandas`, just convert the `dict` to dataframe and export the dataframe to HTML.

Comment: @glibdud It is part of a much larger problem. I have tried different methods. The closest I got was rearranging the values to get each row in the displayed table as a value in a dict. 
count = 1
variables = {}
for keys in values[6]: #using keys in 
  while count < 7:
      variables[keys] = values[count][keys]
    count += 1
  count = 1
trying to get {key1: {b,e,g,i,k,m}, key2: {d,f,h,j,l,n}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Hope this helps,.

In your input, you need to ensure that there are single quotes around the keys(`'server1'`, `'server2'`,.... ). Otherwise, you can build your dictionary in Python.

```py
>>> values = {
...     'server1' : {'key1' : 'b', 'key2' : 'd'},
...     'server2' : {'key1' : 'e', 'key2' : 'f'},
...     'server3' : {'key1' : 'g', 'key2' : 'h'},
...     'server4' : {'key1' : 'i', 'key2' : 'j'},
...     'server5' : {'key1' : 'k', 'key2' : 'l'},
...     'server6' : {'key1' : 'm', 'key2' : 'n'},
... }
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(values)
>>> df
     server1 server2 server3 server4 server5 server6
key1       b       e       g       i       k       m
key2       d       f       h       j       l       n
```

To conver to HTML format

```py
>>> df.to_html()
'<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>server1</th>\n      <th>server2</th>\n      <th>server3</th>\n      <th>server4</th>\n      <th>server5</th>\n      <th>server6</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>key1</th>\n      <td>b</td>\n      <td>e</td>\n      <td>g</td>\n      <td>i</td>\n      <td>k</td>\n      <td>m</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>key2</th>\n      <td>d</td>\n      <td>f</td>\n      <td>h</td>\n      <td>j</td>\n      <td>l</td>\n      <td>n</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>'
>>>
```

Using pandas `to_html`, you can get your HTML data.